# Sum of squares function

Tags: python, function, sum

I'm trying to code the sum of squares in python and I'm pretty new to this.

This is what I have for now:

```
n=int(input("n="))

def sumsquare(n):
    sum=0
    i=0
    while(n<=i):
        sum= sum + i**2
        i= i+1
    return sum
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to make the user choose a number, and based on that number I want to calculate the sum of squares, and `return "The sum of square is ___"`

Comment: you lost the `i += 1` in the while loop.

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: @Ares , well thats the code I wrote, but i'm not sure  it's right.. When I execute it, it doesn't return anything

Comment: @RockyLi I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @JaelNguyen That's because you did not increment `i` in the loop and got stuck with a infinite loop, you need to increment i by 1 in that while loop, i.e. `i += 1`

Comment: Your function code is not indented properly. It is also missing a `return` statement and as was stated it's missing `i+=1` in the while loop.

Comment: @RockyLi I used your code, but still when I print (sumsquare(n)) it gives me 0 for some reason

Comment: @JaelNguyen that's because while should be `(i<=n)` instead of `(n<=i)`, I missed that one, fixed down below.

Answer (score 2):

the pythonic way is `sum(x ** 2 for x in range(1, n + 1))`

Comment: agreed. so much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input("n="))

def sumsquare(n):
    sum=0
    i=0
    while(i<=n):
        sum= sum + i**2
        i += 1
    return sum

# print(sumsquare(n))
print('the sum of square is {}'.format(sumsquare(n)))
```

for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the function `pow` to the `range` and `sum` that

```
print(sum(map(lambda x: pow(x, 2), range(n+1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def square(n):
   return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
   sum = 0
   for n in range(x):
      sum += square(n)
   return sum

print(sum_squares(10))
```

//should be answer 285

this is the answer of your question .

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `square()` and also return the integer output like this. The O/P would be the sum of the squares of the range you are going to provide:

```py
#Returns Square of N
def square(n):
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
    sum = 0
    for n in range(x):      #loops through the range of X
        sum += int(square(n)) #calling for the square of N making sure it is in integer format                           
    return sum

print(sum_squares(10)) #285
print(sum_squares(3)) #14
```